# How to differentiate between left alt key and right alt key in javascript key event and?

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events

I am working on a project which require hotkeys implementation. It require `Alt + Q` for some purpose. I have implemented it but the problem is that it is working only for left side `Alt` key but when I press `Alt + Q` with right side Alt key, then it does not work. So I want to know how can I implement right Alt key in my project using javascript.

Comment: Could you add in some code that you're using to detect the keystrokes?

Comment: I tried that but didn't find any difference between left and right alt keys.

Comment: event.key and event.code are different for both alt keys. 

Left alt:
event.key is Alt
event.code is AltLeft

Right alt:
event.key is AltGraph
event.code is AltRight

Answer (score 1):

DOM3 added a `location` property of keyboard events (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/location)) (earlier versions had a keyLocation property instead) which does what you want and is implemented in recent versions of all major browsers.

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
  alert(e.location || e.keyLocation); // '1' for LeftAlt, and '2' for RightAlt
}
```